# Is $1.r=r.1=r$ for a Non Commutative Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am new to ring theory.
As per one of the axioms of a ring $R$ we have $\forall$ $r \in R$ ,$\:$$\exists$ $1 \in R$ such that $$1.r=r.1=r \tag{1}$$

So this is  definitely commutative property for $1$ and $r$

Is this scenario true even for Non commutative Ring?

Does it mean if $\forall$ $a,b \in R$ ,$a.b \ne b.a$ Then $R$ is Non Commutative with an exception of $(1)$?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is. $1r = r1 = r$ for any ring $R$, whether commutative or not. You don't need to check for all $a,b \in R$ to conclude a ring is non-commutative. A single case where $ab \neq ba$ is enough to show the ring is noncommutative.

Comment: In general, the prefix 'non' in algebra stands for "not necessarily". If something truely doesn't have certain property, one use 'not' instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition of the multiplicative identity, it's indeed true $1 \cdot r = r \cdot 1 = r$ for any $r \in R$.

However, your second assertion is false. We say that $R$ is non-commutative if **there exists** $a,b \in R$ such that $ab \neq ba$, and not necessarily all. An example is the ring of $2 \times 2$ real matrices $\mathcal{M}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$, which is not commutative, but diagonal matrices commute with each other.